# Use of hasNextLine in Java, won't read NextLine after NextInt

Tags: java, string, integer

I am trying to get this to work

```
 System.out.println("Please enter what SOCKET NUMBER you" + 
"wish to connect to");   
            int sockname = Integer.parseInt(inFromUser.nextLine());

   System.out.println("Please enter what HOSTNAME you" + 
"wish to connect to");
   String hostname = inFromUser.nextLine();
```

The problem is that I can't get hostname to equal whatever the user input.  I thought it had to do with hasNext or a variant of that, but I'm not sure.  Any thoughts?

Comment: what are you getting in hostname?

Comment: What's inFromUser?  Are you using Scanner?  Did you verify that sockname holds what you expect?  If it does, then hostname should indeed get the text on the following line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be "\n" in the input buffer after nextLine(), so next call just reads it and returns. You need to clear the buffer after reading int

```
inFromUser.skip("\\n+");
```

Answer (score 1):

java.io.BufferedReader has a readLine() method.  Use that.  If you're using Scanner.nextLine(), then you should know that if your position is just before a newline, you'll get an empty string.  However, the next nextLine would indeed return a full line of text (the same as readLine would).